# What AppInsights queries return actionable data for Azure B2C authentication?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, appinsights

In part of writing this question to remind myself to add this feature to my implementation of B2C for trustlane, what is the AppInsights REST query that would help me alert for and recreate this dialog in a B2C OIDC or OAUTH API session?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C doesn’t store a device fingerprint and doesn’t keep a state of the sessions.

You could use this as a trigger your flow, and collect the user agent
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-unknown-devices

For sending the custom email, when above flow triggers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid

And Claims Resolvers to get the IP to send to the email.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview